# How to switch user in Docker container with User Namespaces

Tags: docker, setuid, linux-namespaces

I am running dockerd 19.03.1, build 74b1e89 with user namespaces enabled on a dedicated ID range

```
 cat > /etc/sub{uid,gid}
 dockeruser:120000:10000
```

I need to switch in a container from root to a dedicated user, which I create as

```
ARG USERID=26551
ENV runUID=${USERID}
ARG GROUPID=26551
ENV runGID=${GROUPID}
ARG USERNAME='testuser'
ENV runUSER=${USERNAME}
ARG groupNAME='testgroup'
ENV runGROUP=${groupNAME}
RUN groupadd -g ${runGID}  ${runGROUP} && useradd -u ${runUID} -g ${runGID} -r ${runUSER}
```

However, I cannot switch in the container context to the user. *su* as well as replacements as *gosu* fail similar to

```
[root@1d5594cd99a0 /]# su - testuser ls
su: cannot set groups: Invalid argument
```

According to the [documentation on user namespace mapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), this might be a caveat and would affect all binaries relying on *setuid* or/and such as *su* checking for the actual binary owner.

It is possible to run commands/binaries in a Docker container under another user in the container context with user namespaces enabled for dockerd?

Answer (score 2):

**answering to my problem**

I had not enough subuids/subgids defined for the user namespace.

**before**

```
/etc/subuid
/etc/subgid
  dockeruser:120000:10000
```

and I created an user in the container with UID=26551 - where 26551  lies not within [120000,120000+10000] and thus switching to that user failed.

**fix**

extending the subuid and subgid range to [200000,200000+100000] and actually include the UID

```
/etc/subuid
/etc/subgid
   dockeruser:200000:100000
```